# Logging in Spark | Impact of Lazy Evaluation on Logging

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below logical flow of spark code written in Java. I  need to capture time of each ith iteration.

```
// Start Spark Job - create configuration and spark context
for ( i < 10)
{

log.info("Start Time of i" + new Date())
    DataFrameObj.Count
    sqlContext.sql("select * from employee")
    SaveAsTextFile
log.info("End Time  Time of i" + new Date())
}
//Exit Spark Job
```

Will this logging behave correctly ? I am in confusion that logging will take place but actual execution time will be different because of Lazy evaluation nature of Spark .

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Conditional loops like for will enforce sequential execution of the spark transformations and actions. Your case you can get the expected time consuming for each action.

```
val  testDF = sc.parallelize(List(("a", "b", "c", "d"))).toDF()  
for (i <- 1.until( 10 )) {
      println( "Start Time of " + i + new Date() )
      testDF.show( i )
      println( "End Time  Time of " + i + new Date() )
    }
```

Alternate way to enable spark parallelism is using Scala (java 8 might have similar feature) collections par feature like below.

```
 1.until( 10 ).par.foreach( i => {
      println( "Start Time of " + i + new Date() )
      testDF.show( i )
      println( "End Time  Time of " + i + new Date() )
    }
    )
```